# why must \$"i"\$ of the current source in the figure be the \$"i_{rms}"\$,not \$i_m\$?

Tags: current

Calculate the average power which  \$5Ω\$ resistor consume
[image]

The solution is

[image]

To be honest,i don't know why can the current be calculate like that,that is ,\$\sqrt{\frac{i_{rms}^2 \times t }{T}}\$

Here is my calculation,but the answer is not 52.5W

\$P_{avg}=\frac{P_{total}}{T}=\frac{P_{total}}{3}\$,and \$P=IV=I^2R\$ 
,so

\$P_{total}=P_{1s}+P_{2s}+P_{3s}=[(\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}} \times \frac{15}{15+5})^2+(\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \times \frac{15}{15+5})^2+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \times \frac{15}{15+5})^2\ ]\times 5 =78.75\$

\$P_{avg}=\frac{P_{total}}{T}=\frac{78.75}{3}=26.25W\$

Now ,i find what is the main reason that my answer is not the same as solution,i think the \$"i"\$ of the current source in  the figure is the \$i_m\$,but the solution think this \$"i"\$ should be \$"i_{rms}"\$ ,and the relation between \$i_m\$ and \$i_{rms}\$ is that \$i_{rms}=\frac{i_m}{\sqrt{2}}\$,so i want to ask why must \$"i"\$ in the figure be the  \$"i_{rms}"\$,not \$i_m\$?

Comment: Calculating rms from peak by dividing peak by sqrt(2) is applied to sinusoidal waves. By the way, why did you take \$P=I^2/R\$?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Ops! terrible mistake,\$P=I^2R\$

Comment: If current drops to 0 amps at the 3 second point (as indicated on your graph) then all the answers are wrong. What happens after the 3 second point is unclear so it can't be answered without assumptions such as: *it remains at zero amps until 4 seconds then starts over again*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first set of equations, the RMS value of current is taken equal to the current levels shown in the graph.  This is correct because, during each 1 second period, the current is constant.  For a constant (DC) current the RMS value is equal to the constant value. This is because the RMS value of a current is defined to be the DC current that generates the same amount of heat in a resistor. In your equation, you divided the constant current value by the square root of 2 in an apparent attempt to calculate the RMS value. This is not correct for a constant current as explained above.  It is correct for a sine wave current if it is the peak value that is divided. This is why you did not get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated, the instantaneous current through the 5 Ω resistor is

$$
i_{5 \Omega} = \frac{15\,i}{15+5}=0.75\,i
$$

The instantaneous power dissipation at time \$t\$ in an ideal, constant-valued resistance \$R\$ is

$$
p(t) = i^2(t)\,R
$$

*(NB: In your analysis, you incorrectly calculated the resistor's power dissipation as \$P=I^2/R\$.)*

The average power dissipation \$\bar{p}\$ in an ideal, constant-valued resistance \$R\$ during the time interval \$[t_0,t]\$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
\bar{p} &= \frac{1}{t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^{t}p(\tau)\,\mathrm{d\tau}\\
&= \frac{1}{t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^{t}i^2(\tau)\,R\;\mathrm{d\tau}\\
&= \frac{R}{t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^{t}i^2(\tau)\;\mathrm{d\tau}
\end{align*}
$$

In your case the time interval is \$[0,3]\,\mathrm{s}\$, the "test" resistance is the 5 Ω resistor, and the "test" current is the current through the 5 Ω resistor, \$i_{5\Omega}=0.75\,i(\tau)\$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\bar{p}_{5\Omega} &= \frac{5\,\mathrm{\Omega}}{(3-0)\,\mathrm{s}} \int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}i_{5\Omega}^2(\tau)\;\mathrm{d\tau}\\
&= \frac{5\,\mathrm{\Omega}}{3\,\mathrm{s}} \int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}\left ( 0.75\,i(\tau) \right )^2\;\mathrm{d\tau}\\
&= \frac{5\,\mathrm{\Omega} \cdot 0.75^2}{3\,\mathrm{s}} \int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}i^2(\tau)\;\mathrm{d\tau}
\end{align*}
$$

The current plot has three DC sections, each with a duration of \$1\,\mathrm{s}\$; therefore, the definite integral can be solved by inspection as,

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}i^2(\tau)\;\mathrm{d\tau} &= \int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{1\,\mathrm{s}}6^2\;\mathrm{d\tau} + \int_{1\,\mathrm{s}}^{2\,\mathrm{s}}4^2\;\mathrm{d\tau} + \int_{2\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}2^2\;\mathrm{d\tau} \\
&= 36\int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{1\,\mathrm{s}}\mathrm{d\tau} + 16\int_{1\,\mathrm{s}}^{2\,\mathrm{s}}\mathrm{d\tau} + 4\int_{2\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}\mathrm{d\tau} \\
&= 36 \cdot (1-0) + 16 \cdot (2-1) + 4 \cdot (3-2) \\
&= 56\,\mathrm{A^2\,s}
\end{align*}
$$

Use this result to calculate the average power in the 5 Ω resistor:

$$
\begin{align*}
\bar{p}_{5\Omega} &= \frac{5\,\mathrm{\Omega}\cdot0.75^2}{3\,\mathrm{s}} \int_{0\,\mathrm{s}}^{3\,\mathrm{s}}i^2(\tau)\;\mathrm{d\tau}\\
&= \frac{5\,\mathrm{\Omega}\cdot 0.75^2}{3\,\mathrm{s}} \cdot 56\,A^2\,s\\
&= 52.5\,\mathrm{W}
\end{align*}
$$

*(NB: As a general rule, use the instantaneous value of current or voltage, not the RMS value, when calculating average values.)*